# Elassandra not indexing UDT

Tags: elassandra

This error occurs with elassandra 5.5.018 and 6.2.3.2.
I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TYPE applicationinfo (
    industry text,
    area_of_application text,
    product_group text,
    sic_code text,
    conveyed_product text,
    flowability text,
    viscosity text,
    solids_content text,
    size_of_solids text,
    concentration text,
    composition text,
    specific_gravity text,
    ph_value text,
    product_temperature_min int,
    product_temperature_max int
);


CREATE TABLE deviceinfo (
    id text,
    "applicationinfo" applicationinfo
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

In my test-case there are some (about 100 entries inserted).
When i try to create an elastic index for the deviceinfo table it fails with this exception:

```
2018-07-04 14:49:56,894 ERROR [SecondaryIndexManagement:3] CassandraDaemon.java:231 uncaughtException Exception in thread Thread[SecondaryIndexManagement:3,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.Throwables.maybeFail(Throwables.java:51)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:373)
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:392)
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:367)
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:288)
    at org.elassandra.index.ElasticSecondaryIndex.lambda$getInitializationTask$5(ElasticSecondaryIndex.java:2266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:366)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering own question. The issue has been resolved here:

https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/issues/210

The solution is to freeze the udt fields:

```
CREATE TABLE deviceinfo (
    id text,
    "applicationinfo" frozen<applicationinfo>,
    baseinfo frozen<baseinfo>,
    "product" frozen<product>,
    "specification" frozen<specification>,
    "technicaldata" frozen<technicaldata>,
    "customer" frozen<customer>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```